# In the Physics, book IV, chapter 5, what does Aristotle mean by stating that a body of uncontained water would show a circular motion?

Tags: aristotle

In the Physics, book IV, chapter 6, Aristotle writes (212a31-32):

> If there were to be water that had not a container, the parts of it
> will be moved, while the whole will be moved in one sense but not in
> another. For as a whole it does not simultaneously change its place,
> though it will be moved in a circle; for this place is the place of
> its parts.

On what grounds does Aristotle claim that a body of uncontained water would, as a whole 'be moved in a circle'?

Comment: I think this question is more likely to get an answer at some forum about history of science and mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

The details are a bit murky, but it seems likely that this refers to the experiment (thought-experiment) known as the "bucket" experiment. I found this source, but am not at all sure how reliable it is. [Empedocles, Newton the Centrifugal Force and Their Bucket Experiments](http://redshift.vif.com/JournalFiles/V20NO3PDF/HORS-17-ASS.pdf) You will certainly spot that the word "uncontained" needs to be understood as meaning "not contained in a closed container".

Comment: +1 This is a good lead. I w ould add for the OP that the following physics terms that might by used to day to understand the passage are: dynamic equilibrium, centripital acceleration, Coriolis effect, and gyroscope.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question spot on, since this oblique paragraph of Aristotle seems to have not gained enough attention. Let us expand on the question as a case of interpreting Aristotle.

It should be emphasised at the outset that, though the traditional title of the book is *Physics* (Φυσική), regarding our contemporary use of the words, it is appropriate to view the book as a treatise on [natural philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_philosophy). Hence, Aristotle's discourse ought to be received in that perspective.

First, the original paragraph in full (the bold are mine):

> Ὧι μὲν οὖν σώματι ἔστι τι ἐκτὸς σῶμα περιέχον αὐτό, τοῦτο ἔστιν ἐν
> τόπῳ, ᾧ δὲ μή, οὔ. διὸ κἂν ὕδωρ γένηται τοιοῦτο, τὰ μὲν μόρια
> κινήσεται αὐτοῦ (περιέχεται γὰρ ὑπ' ἀλλήλων), τὸ δὲ **πᾶν** ἔστι μὲν ὡς
> κινήσεται ἔστι δ' ὡς οὔ. ὡς μὲν γὰρ **ὅλον**, ἅμα τὸν τόπον οὐ μεταβάλλει,
> **κύκλῳ** δὲ κινεῖται —τῶν μορίων γὰρ οὗτος ὁ τόπος— καὶ ἄνω μὲν καὶ κάτω
> οὔ, **κύκλῳ** δ' ἔνια· τὰ δὲ καὶ ἄνω καὶ κάτω, ὅσα ἔχει πύκνωσιν καὶ
> μάνωσιν.

A quite literal [translation of it by R. P. Hardie and R. K. Gaye](http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/physics.4.iv.html) (*The Complete Works of Aristotle: The Revised Oxford Translation*, edited by J. Barnes, vol. I) is as follows (the corresponding bold are mine):

> If then a body has another body outside it and containing it, it is in
> place, and if not, not. That is why, even if there were to be water
> which had not a container, the parts of it will be moved (for one part
> is contained in another), while **the whole** will be moved in one sense,
> but not in another. For as **a whole** it does not simultaneously change
> its place, though it will be moved **in a circle**; for this place is the
> place of its parts. And some parts are moved, not up and down, but **in
> a circle**; others up and down, such things namely as admit of
> condensation and rarefaction.

Aristotle talks here about “place” (τόπος), one of his ten categories (literally, “where”, πού) and “water”, one of his four terrestrial elements, signalling that the issue at stake is a fundamental one.

Aristotle's conception of place deserves particular examination. But, not to digress far, we shall be content with noting that he defines the place of a thing as “the innermost motionless boundary of what contains” (*Phys*., 212a20). That is, the place is determined by a “container”, whether it is natural, like river bed and banks, or artificial, like a jug. For a broad discussion, one may refer to Edward Casey's *The Fate of Place: A Philosophical History* (University of California Press, 1997).

Another point we have to notice is a terminological distinction Aristotle makes and sticks to. Aristotle differentiates two types of circular motion: The one that can be said to be “on a circle” (**κύκλον** φέρεσθαι) is effectively accidental, demanding re-direction so that the thing keeps in a circular track. In contrast, the motion “in circle” (**κύκλῳ** φέρεσθαι) is effectively essential, the beginning and ending points are naturally the same, an excellent example of which is the rotation of celestial spheres according to the Aristotelian description of the Cosmos. The type mentioned in this paragraph is the latter one; thus, Aristotle wants us to consider a circular (or, rotational) motion of water that is naturally so.

A difference that the translators seem to have overlooked is that between πᾶν and ὅλον. Although these two words may be interchangeable in some contexts, they are not synonymous. While πᾶν (corresponding to the first “whole” in the translation) signifying “all of” (parts, elements, etc.) does not imply a formation of unity, ὅλον (corresponding to the second “whole” in the translation) does.

In light of these remarks, we can outline Aristotle's explanation: We can answer where something is only if we could specify where a (relatively) motionless container surrounds it. But in case that water, in a generic sense, does not have a definite container, what could we say about its place, then? All the parts of water (the first “whole”) have place by themselves, since they move surrounded by other parts of water that act like a container. Thus, the parts move in one sense, but as a unity (the second “whole”), they do not, because, as a unity, they do not change their place. Some parts of water move up and down (typically, evaporation and condensation), others make a *natural* circular motion. Therefore, even though water appears to be in neither artificial nor natural vessel, it is not “unplaced”: It has parts in motion, but as a unity, it is stationary “somewhere”.

What Aristotle tells may strike us as a situation more abstract than a thought-experiment, but it is not. We need to recall the *natural places* of the elements to make sense of these (the diagram is borrowed from “Logical and Illogical Exegeses of Hydrometeorological Phenomena in Ancient Greece” (conference paper) by Koutsoyiannis et al., 2006):

[image]

Comparing Aristotle's description with the diagram, we realise that Aristotle actually expands on the natural place of water (as an example) in respect of his conception of place. The interpretative translation by P.H. Wicksteed and F.M. Cornford, [published in the series of Loeb Classical Librar](https://ttps://archive.org/details/aristotlephysics0000tran/)y, may help further articulate Aristotle's account:

> It follows that if a body is encompassed by another body, external to
> it, it is ‘in a place’; but if not, not. As to such an ‘unplaced’ body
> (be it water or anything else) its parts may be in motion, for they
> embrace each other, but as a whole it can be said to ‘move’ only in a
> special sense. For as a whole it cannot change its collective place.
> But it may have a motion of rotation, which motion is what constitutes
> the ‘kind of place’ with respect to which the rotating parts move.
>
> Now in the universe there are some parts which do not move up and down
> but do rotate; and others (such as are susceptible to condensation and
> rarefication) which can either rotate or move up and down.